# Can I reset my quests?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have made a huge mistake.

In Fallout Shelter, you can now go on quests. On these quests, like sending dwellers to the Wasteland, you can assign them Stimpacks and Radaway, and then heal them as necessary as they develop through the quest.

However, on one of the praticuarly more difficult quests, I missed assigning them with the Stimpacks and Radaway, and so they are unable to complete the quest (they keep dying about halfway through)*.

Is there anyway I can restart the quest to assign them the proper healing items to complete the quest?

---

*Yes I am aware that you find items throughout the quest (if you're lucky) however these are not enough to sustain the team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can abandon the quest, call them back and then redo the quest with the appropriate amount of stimpacks and radaways. Of course, in order to do this you need to wait for your dwellers to get back to the vault and then back to quest's location.

If it's a daily quest and the day passes in the meantime then you will be given another daily quest. Use Nuka Cola Quantum if you have, to be sure you don't miss the quest.